# stop carousel in flash as3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, carousel

Hi I founded a flash as3 carousel by searching in internet. The code is:

```
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 1.7;
var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var radiusX:Number = 180;
var radiusY:Number = 50;
var speed:Number = 0.1;
var minSpeed:Number = -0.05;
var maxSpeed:Number = 0.05;
var rangeSpeed:Number = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
var minY:Number = centerY - radiusY;
var maxY:Number = centerY + radiusY;
var rangeY:Number = maxY - minY;
var minScale:Number = 0.2;
var maxScale:Number = 1.0;
var rangeScale:Number = maxScale - minScale;
var itemArray:Array = new Array();
itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(canvas);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    canvas.addChild(itemArray[i]);
    itemArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stop);
    itemArray[i].itemAngle = Math.PI * 2 / itemArray.length * i;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}



function animate(e:Event):void
{
    speed = mouseX / stage.stageWidth * rangeSpeed + minSpeed;
    e.currentTarget.x = Math.cos(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusX + centerX;
    e.currentTarget.y = Math.sin(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusY + centerY;
    e.currentTarget.itemAngle += speed;
    itemArray.sortOn("y");

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    {
        canvas.setChildIndex(itemArray[i], i);
        var pct:Number = (itemArray[i].y - minY) / rangeY;
        var scale:Number = pct * rangeScale + minScale;
        itemArray[i].scaleX = itemArray[i].scaleY = scale;
    }
}
function stop(event:MouseEvent):void {


}
```

Now, after some modification,  with the function stop I want to stop the carousel by clicking on one element on the layer, but I don't know how I can do this! Someone can help me?

Regards`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't name a function `stop` unless you plan to override it, which in this case you aren't. To stop the carousel from spinning you simply need to remove the `ENTER_FRAME` event. I renamed your `stop` function to `stopAnimate`

```
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 1.7;
var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var radiusX:Number = 180;
var radiusY:Number = 50;
var speed:Number = 0.1;
var minSpeed:Number = -0.05;
var maxSpeed:Number = 0.05;
var rangeSpeed:Number = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
var minY:Number = centerY - radiusY;
var maxY:Number = centerY + radiusY;
var rangeY:Number = maxY - minY;
var minScale:Number = 0.2;
var maxScale:Number = 1.0;
var rangeScale:Number = maxScale - minScale;
var itemArray:Array = new Array();
itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

itemArray.push(new cubeblue());

var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(canvas);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    canvas.addChild(itemArray[i]);
    itemArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopAnimate);
    itemArray[i].itemAngle = Math.PI * 2 / itemArray.length * i;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}

function animate(e:Event):void
{
    speed = mouseX / stage.stageWidth * rangeSpeed + minSpeed;
    e.currentTarget.x = Math.cos(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusX + centerX;
    e.currentTarget.y = Math.sin(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusY + centerY;
    e.currentTarget.itemAngle += speed;
    itemArray.sortOn("y");

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    {
        canvas.setChildIndex(itemArray[i], i);
        var pct:Number = (itemArray[i].y - minY) / rangeY;
        var scale:Number = pct * rangeScale + minScale;
        itemArray[i].scaleX = itemArray[i].scaleY = scale;
    }
}

function stopAnimate(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    {
        itemArray[i].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
    }
}
```

now to renable the animation, you can simply add a click event to lets say a button and that function will perform

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}
```

which will just add the `ENTER_FRAME` event back on the movie clips in `itemArray`

Comment: Thank you so much :D And now when I have stopped the carousel I can drag an element?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. Check this resource http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag()